# Cannot have two renders using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I am trying to set the title of the index page to be "Sign In" and at the same time retrieving data from mongodb. I learned this technique from this page - http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/

It seems that I cannot have two renders because if I do I get the cannot read from undefined error. If I just keep the one that help me retrieving data, I cannot have the title set properly. Any idea what I should do?

Here are the two related pieces of codes. 
This one is from the index.js in routes folder.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    next();
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var db = req.db;
    var accounts = db.get('accountInfo');
    accounts.find({}, {}, function(err, docs) {
        res.render('index', {
            "accounts" : docs
        });
    });
});

router.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
    res.render('signup', { title: 'Create New Account' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And this is from the index.jade

```
ul
    each account, i in accounts
        li
            p= account.username
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code.The two renders are unrelated and should never both be hit during a single request. I suspect you are misdiagnosing the problem and/or misunderstanding express routing and jade templating. res.render should only ever be called once per request.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I should combine the two into one. Otherwise the server will try to put two windows' information on one single screen.